# How to use Google Recaptchav.3 in Nuxtjs v.3

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3, recaptcha-v3

I want to use Google Recaptcha **without** using any external library in Nuxt3, this is `sign-in page` script section

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
useHead({
  script: [
    {
      hid: 'gtm-script1',
      src: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js',
      defer: true
    }]
})
function onSubmit(token) {
  console.log(token)
}
</script>
```

and the template section

```html
<template>
  <button class="g-recaptcha"
    data-sitekey="6LfJox8gAAAAADKdDuAYHZqpvkRmArUzyWv"
    data-callback="onSubmit"
    data-action="submit"
  >
    Submit
  </button>
</template>
```

then when I click on the **Submit** button, I have the following error

> ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: onSubmit